# Outlet collections, i want to access the properties(hidden) for my UIimageview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, iboutletcollection

I can only access the id of my outlet collection and an id does not have a hidden property

This is my outlet collection

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *hearts;
```

and this is when I try to call it, and change it to hidden.

```
[self.hearts objectAtIndex:0].hidden =YES;
```

I can not because objectAtIndex only returns an id

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try enumerating the objects in the collection, using the type you expect (eg, `for (UIView *heartView in self.hearts)`) or first cast the objectAtIndex:0 and then set the hidden property.

Comment: yea i just figured it out,I casted it. Thanks for help!